# VBA for each loop to paste data from one sheet to bottom of another

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to run a loop with a list of names. Each name will change the value of one cell which will then change the hosts of values on another sheet.

The problem is that when I run the loop, the last cell on the list value replaces all the other values.

```
Sub MasterBrandList()

  Dim ChangingBrand As String, PreVBAData As Worksheet, VBAData As Worksheet, lr As Long, rng As Range

  For Each c In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Pivots_allbrands").Range("A2:A10").Cells

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Pivots_allbrands").Range("M1").Value = c.Value

    Set PreVBAData = Sheets("PreVBAData")
    Set VBAData = Sheets("VBAData")

    lr = PreVBAData.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = PreVBAData.Range("A2:A" & lr)

    rng.EntireRow.Copy VBAData.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)(2)

  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: what data are you trying to copy/paste here `rng.EntireRow.Copy VBAData.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)(2)` ? I mean is it formulas or plain values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is because you trying to copy formulas here:

```
rng.EntireRow.Copy VBAData.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)(2)
```

Replace this line with following:

```
rng.EntireRow.Copy    
Set r = VBAData.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)(2)
r.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```